# Does dropping a partition from hive table drops it's subpartitions?

Tags: hive, hive-partitions

I have an external hive table which has partitions like year = 2017, year = 2018 and inside them I've partitions for each month for year = 2017 and year = 2018 as well.

My questions are:

1. If I drop partition year = 2017, will it drop all the month partitions for year = 2017?
2. what will happen in case of internal tables?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, hive **drops all the month partitions/sub partititons including data in file system(HDFS..etc)** inside year=2017 in case of internal tables.

In case of external tables **data will not be dropped from file system(HDFS) but hive drops the partition information** from hive table metadata.

Comment: Thanks @Shu. Also one more doubt is if I delete the 2017 HDFS directory directly without running the drop partition command on hive CLI, will the changes get reflected in table also automatically ? Also will it cause any kind of issues in hive meratada store (which is derby i guess).

Comment: If we delete hdfs directly even if the table is external/internal table doesn't matter hive doesn't know about the dropped directories until we run msck repair table/drop partition statement from hive. The issue will be job will fail to find the directory(which is dropped already in HDFS)